# Hive {Case..when} is not recognizing the hiveconf variable passed from shell script

Tags: hive, case-when

I am getting below error while running hive query.

```
FAILED: ParseException line 36:106 cannot recognize input near '$' '{' 'hiveconf' in expression specification
```

Here is my requirement:
I have two roll_condition..

```
if roll_cond=1 then execute something
if roll_cond=2 then execute something
```

Trying to achieve this with the below code

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE db.tab_name partition(yr,mon)
select xxxx,xxx,xx,xx
from db.tab_name
left join db.name
on condition
where case when ${hiveconf:roll_cond}=1 then yr = case 
           when ${hiveconf:refresh_yr} <> 0 then ${hiveconf:refresh_yr} 
              else year(current_date) end;
           when ${hiveconf:roll_cond}=2 then condition end;
```

So when I run the script with '1' it ran fine but when I give '2' it is giving me above mentioned error.

Please suggest where the code is failing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a syntax error on " else year(current_date) end; ".  There should be no semicolon until the last condition.

Comment: Not getting, what you are achieving by setting `yr` in where clause!